# Why do we use private in Java if we have reflection

Tags: java, reflection, private

Why do we need to use private field if we can still ecsess it with the reflection API?
I know for what private is for but reflection contrary the private field.

Comment: Because `private` is not a security mechanism.  It is a primarily mechanism for limiting unwanted coupling between classes.  (And sometimes, you need that coupling *despite* the original class designer's intentions ... hence the reflective solution.)

Comment: `private` is (in fact, all access modifiers are) not just a way to control how people interact with your object, but it is also a way to _define_ the object and what it intends to be used for.